# Why is deploying ecr image to ecs uses the first (and not latest) task definition?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, circleci, aws-code-deploy, ecs-taskdefinition

I use circleci with orbs: aws/ecr, aws/ecs that uploads the new docker image, and supposed to update ecs service.

My issue is that it uses the first, and not the latest task definition, and cannot seem to find a way to set the deployment to update with the latest task definition.

I use terraform to manage my infrastructure which looks like:

```
# Get subnets
data "aws_subnets" "subnets" {
  filter {
    name   = "vpc-id"
    values = [var.vpc_id]
  }
}

# Get security groups
data "aws_security_groups" "security_groups" {
  filter {
    name   = "vpc-id"
    values = [var.vpc_id]
  }
}

# Create load balancer
resource "aws_lb" "load_balancer" {
  name = "${var.app_name}-load-balancer-${var.env}"
  subnets = data.aws_subnets.subnets.ids
  security_groups = data.aws_security_groups.security_groups.ids
  load_balancer_type = "application"
  tags = {
    Environment = "${var.env}"
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group" "blue_target" {
  name     = "${var.app_name}-blue-target-${var.env}"
  protocol = "HTTPS"
  port     = var.port
  target_type = "ip"
  vpc_id   = var.vpc_id
  health_check {
    healthy_threshold = 5
    interval = 30
    matcher = 200
    path = "${var.health_check_path}"
    protocol = "HTTPS"
    timeout = 10
    unhealthy_threshold = 2
  }
}
resource "aws_lb_target_group" "green_target" {
  name     = "${var.app_name}-green-target-${var.env}"
  protocol = "HTTPS"
  port     = var.port
  target_type = "ip"
  vpc_id   = var.vpc_id
  health_check {
    healthy_threshold = 5
    interval = 30
    matcher = 200
    path = "${var.health_check_path}"
    protocol = "HTTPS"
    timeout = 10
    unhealthy_threshold = 2
  }
}

data "aws_acm_certificate" "cert" {
    domain      = var.domain
    statuses = ["ISSUED"]
    most_recent = true
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "listener" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.load_balancer.arn
  port              = var.port
  protocol          = "HTTPS"
  ssl_policy        = "ELBSecurityPolicy-2016-08"
  certificate_arn   = data.aws_acm_certificate.cert.arn

  default_action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.blue_target.arn
  }
}

# ECS

resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "cluster" {
  name = "${var.app_name}-cluster-${var.env}"
}

data "aws_ecr_repository" "ecr_repository" {
  name = var.image_repo_name
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "ecs_task_role" {
  name = "EcsTaskRole"
  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Action = "sts:AssumeRole"
        Effect = "Allow"
        Sid    = ""
        Principal = {
          Service = "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
        }
      },
    ]
  })
}
resource "aws_iam_policy" "secrets_manager_read_policy" {
  name        = "SecretsManagerRead"
  description = "Read only access to secrets manager"

  policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17",
    Statement = [
      {
        Sid = "",
        Effect = "Allow",
        Action = [
          "secretsmanager:GetRandomPassword",
          "secretsmanager:GetResourcePolicy",
          "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
          "secretsmanager:DescribeSecret",
          "secretsmanager:ListSecretVersionIds",
          "secretsmanager:ListSecrets"
        ],
        Resource = "*"
      }
    ]
  })
}
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "attach_secrets_manager_read_to_task_role" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.ecs_task_role.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.secrets_manager_read_policy.arn
}
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "attach_s3_read_to_task_role" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.ecs_task_role.name
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess"
}
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "attach_ses_to_task_role" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.ecs_task_role.name
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonSESFullAccess"
}
resource "aws_iam_role" "ecs_exec_role" {
  name = "EcsExecRole"
  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Action = "sts:AssumeRole"
        Effect = "Allow"
        Sid    = ""
        Principal = {
          Service = "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
        }
      },
    ]
  })
}
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "attach_ecs_task_exec_to_exec_role" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.ecs_exec_role.name
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy"
}
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "attach_fault_injection_simulator_to_exec_role" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.ecs_exec_role.name
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSFaultInjectionSimulatorECSAccess"
}

resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "task_def" {
  family = "${var.app_name}-task-def-${var.env}"
  network_mode = "awsvpc"
  task_role_arn = aws_iam_role.ecs_task_role.arn
  execution_role_arn = aws_iam_role.ecs_exec_role.arn
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  cpu = "256"
  memory = "512"
  runtime_platform {
    cpu_architecture = "X86_64"
    operating_system_family = "LINUX"
  }
  container_definitions = jsonencode([
    {
      name      = "${var.app_name}-container-${var.env}"
      image     = "${data.aws_ecr_repository.ecr_repository.repository_url}:latest"
      cpu       = 0
      essential = true
      portMappings = [
        {
          containerPort = var.port
          hostPort      = var.port
        },
      ]
      environment = [
        {
          name = "PORT",
          value = tostring("${var.port}")
        },
        {
          name = "NODE_ENV",
          value = var.env
        }
      ]
      logConfiguration = {
          logDriver = "awslogs"
          options = {
            "awslogs-create-group" = "true"
            "awslogs-group" = "${var.app_name}-task-def-${var.env}"
            "awslogs-region" = "${var.region}"
            "awslogs-stream-prefix" = "ecs"
          }
        }
    },
  ])
}

resource "aws_ecs_service" "service" {
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      task_definition,
      load_balancer,
    ]
  }
  cluster = aws_ecs_cluster.cluster.arn
  name = "${var.app_name}-service-${var.env}"
  task_definition = aws_ecs_task_definition.task_def.arn
  load_balancer {
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.blue_target.arn
    container_name = "${var.app_name}-container-${var.env}"
    container_port = var.port
  }
  capacity_provider_strategy {
    capacity_provider = "FARGATE"
    base = 0
    weight = 1
  }
  scheduling_strategy = "REPLICA"
  deployment_controller {
    type = "CODE_DEPLOY"
  }
  platform_version = "1.4.0"
  network_configuration {
    assign_public_ip = true
    subnets = data.aws_subnets.subnets.ids
    security_groups = data.aws_security_groups.security_groups.ids
  }
  desired_count = 1
}

# DEPLOYMENT

resource "aws_codedeploy_app" "codedeploy_app" {
  name = "${var.app_name}-application-${var.env}"
  compute_platform = "ECS"
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "codedeploy_role" {
  name = "CodedeployRole"
  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Action = "sts:AssumeRole"
        Effect = "Allow"
        Sid    = ""
        Principal = {
          Service = "codedeploy.amazonaws.com"
        }
      },
    ]
  })
}
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "attach_codedeploy_role" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.codedeploy_role.name
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSCodeDeployRole"
}
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "attach_codedeploy_role_for_ecs" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.codedeploy_role.name
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSCodeDeployRoleForECS"
}

resource "aws_codedeploy_deployment_group" "deployment_group" {
  app_name = aws_codedeploy_app.codedeploy_app.name
  deployment_config_name = "CodeDeployDefault.ECSAllAtOnce"
  auto_rollback_configuration {
    enabled = true
    events = ["DEPLOYMENT_FAILURE"]
  }
  blue_green_deployment_config {
    deployment_ready_option {
      action_on_timeout = "CONTINUE_DEPLOYMENT"
      wait_time_in_minutes = 0
    }
    terminate_blue_instances_on_deployment_success {
      action                           = "TERMINATE"
      termination_wait_time_in_minutes = 5
    }
  }
  deployment_group_name = "${var.app_name}-deployment-group-${var.env}"
  deployment_style {
    deployment_option = "WITH_TRAFFIC_CONTROL"
    deployment_type = "BLUE_GREEN"
  }
  load_balancer_info {
    target_group_pair_info {
      prod_traffic_route {
        listener_arns = [aws_lb_listener.listener.arn]
      }

      target_group {
        name = aws_lb_target_group.blue_target.name
      }

      target_group {
        name = aws_lb_target_group.green_target.name
      }
    }
  }
  service_role_arn = aws_iam_role.codedeploy_role.arn
  ecs_service {
    service_name = aws_ecs_service.service.name
    cluster_name = aws_ecs_cluster.cluster.name
  }
}

resource "aws_appautoscaling_target" "scalable_target" {
  service_namespace  = "ecs"
  resource_id        = "service/${aws_ecs_cluster.cluster.name}/${aws_ecs_service.service.name}"
  scalable_dimension = "ecs:service:DesiredCount"
  min_capacity       = 1
  max_capacity       = 5
}
resource "aws_appautoscaling_policy" "cpu_scaling_policy" {
  name = "${var.app_name}-cpu-scaling-policy-${var.env}"
  service_namespace = "ecs"
  resource_id = "service/${aws_ecs_cluster.cluster.name}/${aws_ecs_service.service.name}"
  scalable_dimension = "ecs:service:DesiredCount"
  policy_type = "TargetTrackingScaling"
  target_tracking_scaling_policy_configuration {
    target_value = 70
    predefined_metric_specification {
      predefined_metric_type = "ECSServiceAverageCPUUtilization"
    }
    scale_out_cooldown = 300
    scale_in_cooldown = 300
    disable_scale_in = false
  }
}
resource "aws_appautoscaling_policy" "memory_scaling_policy" {
  name = "${var.app_name}-memory-scaling-policy-${var.env}"
  service_namespace = "ecs"
  resource_id = "service/${aws_ecs_cluster.cluster.name}/${aws_ecs_service.service.name}"
  scalable_dimension = "ecs:service:DesiredCount"
  policy_type = "TargetTrackingScaling"
  target_tracking_scaling_policy_configuration {
    target_value = 70
    predefined_metric_specification {
      predefined_metric_type = "ECSServiceAverageMemoryUtilization"
    }
    scale_out_cooldown = 300
    scale_in_cooldown = 300
    disable_scale_in = false
  }
}
```

And my circleci config (the relevant parts):

```
  deploy:
    executor: aws-ecr/default
    working_directory: ~/code
    parameters:
      env:
        type: string
    steps:
      - attach_workspace:
          at: ~/
      - aws-ecr/build-and-push-image:
          # attach-workspace: true
          # create-repo: true
          repo: "test-<< parameters.env >>"
          tag: "latest,${CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM}"
      - aws-ecs/update-service: # orb built-in job
          family: "test-task-def-<< parameters.env >>"
          service-name: "test-service-<< parameters.env >>"
          cluster: "test-cluster-<< parameters.env >>"
          container-image-name-updates: "container=test-container-<< parameters.env >>,tag=${CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM}"
          deployment-controller: "CODE_DEPLOY"
          codedeploy-application-name: "test-application-<< parameters.env >>"
          codedeploy-deployment-group-name: "test-deployment-group-<< parameters.env >>"
          codedeploy-load-balanced-container-name: "test-container-<< parameters.env >>"
          codedeploy-load-balanced-container-port: 3000
```

Can anyone spot why my service isn't using the latest task definition, and the deployments are using the old task definition for the service?

Some additional info:
The deployment created in circleci uses the latest task definition, and it's visible in the deployment revision as well (appspec).

I've made a mistake in the first creation of the task definiton, I used container_definitions.image as an ecr image's id (which is sha id), and it cannot pull images.

The issue is that the ecs service is using that task definition, constantly trying to create tasks, and failing while codedeploy deployment - which is somewhat unexpected, as it should use the new task definition to create new tasks.

So I have a service with wrongly configured task definition, and when I try to fix it, the deployment cannot go through with the fix, because it's using the wrong task definition to create new tasks, and the deployment is stuck.